# SASS example from tutorial does has compiling error

Tags: css, sass

```
$list: adam john wynn mason kuroir

=author-images
  @each $author in $list
    .photo-#{$author}
      background: image-url("avatars/#{$author}.png") no-repeat;

.author-bio
  +author-images
```

Does anyone know why this code sample from http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while is not compiling correctly in SASSMeister?

http://sassmeister.com/gist/b76fdc61130135864989

Comment: Hint:  you're mixing syntaxes.

Comment: $list: adam john wynn mason kuroir;

=author-images {
  @each $author in $list{
    .photo-#{$author} {
      background: image-url("avatars/#{$author}.png") no-repeat; 
    }
  }
}


.author-bio {
  +author-images
}

Comment: Still couldn't quite get this to work.

Comment: As I already stated, you are mixing syntaxes.  I suggest you take the time to look over the official Sass documentation.

Comment: Oh, I see! No wonder it did not look familiar. "=" is a mixin and "+" is an include.